# BFS Graph loop execution

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, breadth-first-search

I am trying to traverse breadth first in graph formed . My graph is in adjacency list by arraylist of arraylist as below

```
void bfs(int root,Graph g)
    {
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[g.al.size()];
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        
        q.add(root);
        
        
        
        visited[root] = true;
        
        while(!q.isEmpty())
        {
            int v = q.remove();
            System.out.print(v);
        
       // **Using for each loop ( i.e. for(int k:g.al.get(v))) works well , but it isn't working with this for loop**
        for(int k= g.al.get(v).get(0) ; k <= g.al.get(v).size() ; k++ )
        {
            if(visited[k]==false)
            {
                visited[k]=true;
                q.add(k);
            }
        }           
        }           
    }
```

My Graph class is as follows :

```
class Graph
    {
        int v;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<>();
        
        Graph(int v)
        {
            this.v = v;
            
            for(int i = 0 ; i < v; i++)
            {
                al.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            }
            
            
        }
    
    public Graph() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    void addEdge(int sr,int des)
    {
        al.get(sr).add(des);
        al.get(des).add(sr);
    }
```

**The for loop in bfs function is executing for the node passed first time only .It adds the elements in queue for the node passed first time. Then after going in while loop not falling under the for loop .**

Comment: It traverse successfully  and printing all vertex on using for each loop i.e. for(int k:g.al.get(v)) but isn't working with normal for loop as shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between **enhanced** for loop and **indexed** for loop is that they iterate through **values** and **indexes** respectively

In your code the `k` variable is an **index**, **not** an actual graph **value**.

The enhanced `for (int k : g.al.get(v)))` goes over all **values** and similar indexed for loop behaviour can be achieved by iterating through **indexes** and fetching a corresponding **value** for each **index**

```java
ArrayList<Integer> list = g.al.get(v);
for (int k = 0 ; k < list.size() ; k++ ) {
    int value = list.get(k);
    if (visited[value] == false) {
         visited[value] = true;
         q.add(value);
    }
}
```